# Use SDL2 with CLion 2020

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, sdl-2, clion

I can't seem to link SDL2 correctly. I am using CLion with MinGW. My CMakeLists.txt looks like this currently, but I tried using the FindSDL2 module floating around, though it always said that it could not find the SDL2 library. This is the only way I've found it to stop giving back errors.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(CBeat)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} "CC:/Development/SDL2_MinGW_32bit/lib/cmake/SDL2")

set(SDL2_DIR C:/Mingw)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(SDL2_LIB_DIR ${SDL2_DIR}/lib)
include_directories(${SDL2_DIR}/include)

add_executable(CBeat main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(CBeat ${SDL2_LIB_DIR}/libSDL2.dll.a ${SDL2_LIB_DIR}/libSDL2main.a ${SDL2_LIB_DIR}/libSDL2.a  -mwindows -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2)
add_definitions(-DSDL_MAIN_HANDLED)
```

Now, the main.cpp looks like this, CLion shows no errors and actually is able to give me suggestions and information in each function, but when running it marks various functions as undefined. I attach evidence. I am so desperate right now, I've been trying to figure out this for days now and nothing seems to work!

```
  #include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

using namespace std;

const int SWIDTH=640, SHEIGHT=420;

int main( int argc, char* args[] ){
SDL_Window* window = NULL;
SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;

if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ) < 0 )
{
    cout<< "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error:" << SDL_GetError << endl;
}
else
{
    window = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SWIDTH, SHEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
    if( window == NULL )
    {
        cout << "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: " << SDL_GetError << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
        SDL_FillRect(screenSurface, NULL,SDL_MapRGB(screenSurface->format, 0xFF,0xFF,0xFF));
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window );
        SDL_Delay( 2000 );
    }
    SDL_DestroyWindow( window );
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;


   }
}
```

[CLion trying to be useful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1REJ.png)

And these are the errors it gives back:

```
    [ 50%] Linking CXX executable CBeat.exe
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\CBeat.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): in function `main':
C:/Users/yello/CLionProjects/CBeat/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/yello/CLionProjects/CBeat/main.cpp:18: undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/yello/CLionProjects/CBeat/main.cpp:25: undefined reference to `SDL_GetWindowSurface'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/yello/CLionProjects/CBeat/main.cpp:26: undefined reference to `SDL_MapRGB'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/yello/CLionProjects/CBeat/main.cpp:26: undefined reference to `SDL_FillRect'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/yello/CLionProjects/CBeat/main.cpp:27: undefined reference to `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/yello/CLionProjects/CBeat/main.cpp:28: undefined reference to `SDL_Delay'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/yello/CLionProjects/CBeat/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyWindow'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/yello/CLionProjects/CBeat/main.cpp:31: undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\CBeat.dir\build.make:88: recipe for target 'CBeat.exe' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:74: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/CBeat.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CBeat.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/CBeat.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/CBeat.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [CBeat] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:81: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/CBeat.dir/rule' failed
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'CBeat' failed
```

Comment: .. Did you copy your SDL2 libraries and headers into `c:/mingw`?  Never do that!

Comment: Also, your CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH has `CC:/...` instead of `C:/`. The referenced path should contain the `sdl2-config.cmake` file In order for `FindSDL2` to work.

Comment: @Botje thanks for answering! Why should i not drop the files into mingw? I believe you but i'd still love to know:) Also, I already changed that double C but the same error occurs, and I think I might not be actually using FindSDL2 since i never link to where it is.